# Can I add a condition to my count based on the group by value

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying the monthly count of active for a given month.
For all months, since our first user, how many users were created and not archived by the end of the month.

given this dataset ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c14273/5))

```sql
create table users(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
   archived_at DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);

insert into users (created_at, archived_at) values ('2020-01-01', null);
insert into users (created_at, archived_at) values ('2020-01-01', null);
insert into users (created_at, archived_at) values ('2020-01-01', '2020-01-02');
insert into users (created_at, archived_at) values ('2020-02-01', null);
```

I'm looking for something like

```
2020-01 -> 2
2020-02 -> 3
```

I'm trying to add a condition to my count to only count users if they were not archived during the current month of the group by

```
select date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m-01') as date, count(*) 
from users 
where archived_at is null or (archived_at BETWEEN date AND last_day(date))
group by date
```

This does not work: **Unknown column 'date' in 'where clause'**

```
select date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m-01') as date, count(CASE WHEN (archived_at > date) then 1 else 0 END) 
from users 
where archived_at is null or (archived_at BETWEEN date AND last_day(date))
group by date;
```

this yields a similar error: **Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'**

Comment: You can't reference a column alias in the `where` clause of the same query.

Comment: You said you want to count when they *not* archived during the same month, so shouldn't it be `NOT BETWEEN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, rewriting my answer. That'll teach me to post anything without testing it.

```
select extract(year_month from created_at) as date, count(*) as count
from users
where archived_at is null or archived_at > last_day(created_at)
group by date;
```

I tested this on MySQL 5.7.27, and given your input data, it produced this result:

```
+--------+-------+
| date   | count |
+--------+-------+
| 202001 |     2 |
| 202002 |     1 |
+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't get either query to work. they both return **Unknown column 'date' in 'where clause'**

Comment: `last_day(date)` should be `last_day(created_at)`

Comment: Fixed. This demonstrates the value of actually testing queries before posting them on SO. But I was trying to get just ONE freaking answer in before you or Gordon Linoff answered. :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin sorry this does not work, I'm assuming you also meant date(created_at) instead of date in the second query, but that returns 2021-01 -> 1, 2021-02 -> null

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to a column alias in the same query, except in the `HAVING` clause.

But in your case you just want to check if the `created_at` and `archived_at` are in the same month, so you can just compare them.

```
SELECT date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m') AS date, SUM(archived_at IS NULL OR archived_at > created_at) AS count
FROM users
WHERE archived_at IS NULL OR YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(archived_at) AND MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(archived_at)
```

Comment: This returns 2020-01 -> 1

Comment: I forgot `archived_at IS NULL`

Comment: This does not give me the results I'm expecting.

Comment: I didn't really understand you description of what you expect. Do you want to count the archives in the same month as creation or not the same month?

Comment: `archived_at BETWEEN date AND last_day(date)` looks like it's the same month.